# How do I query data from a MySQL Database using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a MySQL Database called "business elements", which has 4 columns in it (ID,Username,Password & Level). I want to check if a specific username's (given by `Usernametextbox.text`) "Level" is Admin, Manager or User. These are the 3 values that I want all of my users to have(They are all in the column Level). My connectionstring is `"server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=business elements"` and my table is `users`

Basically I want to check the value of a column with a given user.

All of this is in Visual Basic.

Someone please Help..

Comment: and what's your error message? what have you tried?

Comment: bad post title + no code shown

Comment: Don't know how to start any suggestions..

Comment: try going to youtube, there r a lot of tutorials of everything

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find any :/ How would I go about getting all the values of the column to a string in which I can work with in VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the level for a particular username. It should a good starting point for lots of other functions. I haven't tested it, but it should be pretty close. (Userlevel should match the data type for "level"in the table.)

```
Dim conn as MySqlConnection
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

conn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=business elements;")
conn.Open()

cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT level FROM users WHERE Username=@username LIMIT 1", conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Usernametextbox.Text)
userLevel = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```